# Sorting Vector(Bubble sort) c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have class Date, functions bubbleSort, isAfter and printVector. So my task is: Use the function bubbleSort to sort vector type objects Date(using function isAfter which compares dates). I've done something but it doesn't works, so can anyone help me with this?
Function bubble sort(doesn't works with "Date", works fine with integers ,strings...).
Here is my code:

```
//isAfter
template<>
bool isAfter(const Date &first, const Date &second) {
    if (first.getYear() == second.getYear()) {
        if (first.getMonth() == second.getMonth()) {
            if (first.getDay() == second.getDay()) {
                cout << first.toString() << " is equal to " << second.toString() << endl;
                return false;
            } else if (first.getDay() > second.getDay()) {
                cout << " " << first.toString() << " is after " << " " << second.toString() << endl;
                return true;
            } else if (first.getDay() < second.getDay()) {
                cout << " " << second.toString() << " is after " << " " << first.toString() << endl;
                return true;
            }
        } else if (first.getMonth() > second.getMonth()) {
            cout << " " << first.toString() << " is after " << " " << second.toString() << endl;
            return true;
        } else if (first.getMonth() < second.getMonth()) {
            cout << " " << second.toString() << " is after " << " " << first.toString() << endl;
            return true;
        }
    } else if (first.getYear() > second.getYear()) {
        cout << " " << first.toString() << " is after " << " " << second.toString() << endl;
        return true;
    } else if (first.getYear() < second.getYear()) {
        cout << " " << second.toString() << " is after " << " " << first.toString() << endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//bubbleSort
template<typename T>
void bubbleSort(vector<T> &vec) {
    bool swapp= true;
    while (swapp) {
        swapp= false;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size()- 1; i++) {
            if (vec[i] > vec[i + 1]) {
                swap(vec[i], vec[i + 1]);
                swapp = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

so how can i add isAfter in bubbleSort to work fine with "Date" objects?

Comment: `if (vec[i] > vec[i + 1])` -- Hint:  Replace this line.

Comment: Rename `isAfter` to `operator>`?

Comment: Also, you consistently return true in both branches of every `first.getX() > second.getX()` and `first.getX() < second.getX()`.

Comment: You could have also looked at `std::sort` to see how it handles custom types.

Comment: Temporarily get rid of all of those `cout` statements in the `isAfter` function.  It just adds unnecessary noise to the code, and hides the logic of what is being done.

Comment: Also, that entire `isAfter` function is flawed, as you're returning `true` regardless if the day 1 is less than day 2 or not.  You make the same mistake for a few other parts, where you're returning `true` regardless of whether one component is less than the other.  The simplest solution to me is to just use `std::tie`, and all of this code will just magically work: `template<>bool isAfter(const Date &first, const Date &second) {
    return std::tie(first.getYear(), first.getMonth(), first.getDay() <           std::tie(second.getYear(), second.getMonth(), second.getYear()); }`

Answer (score 2):

If this is always the sort order for dates and you control that type, you could implement the comparison operators `operator<`, `operator>`, `operator<=`, `operator>=`, `operator==` and `operator!=` for that type.

Otherwise, the conventional approach is to modify your sorting algorithm to accept a custom comparator (by convention, having the interface of `operator<`, which requires you to flip your comparison) from its callers, something like:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Compare>
void bubbleSort(vector<T> &vec, Compare compare) {
  // as you currently have, but using compare(a, b) instead of a < b
}

template <typename T>
void bubbleSort(vector<T> &vec) {
  bubbleSort(vec, std::less<>());
}
```

Then callers can use `isAfter` like this:

```cpp
bubbleSort(dates, [](const Date& a, const Date& b) { return isAfter(b, a); });
```

Comment: I have to use the functions that i wrote, i can not add new functions. All i am allowed to do is to make changes inside the functions.

Comment: In that case, simply replace the comparison with a call to `isAfter`. Bear in mind that Stack Overflow users aren't aware of the constraints of a class you may be taking, and are likely to advise what they would do outside a classroom setting.

Comment: I changed this:  if (vec[i] > vec[i + 1])  with this: if (isAfter(vec[i] ,vec[i + 1])) and now is printing infinity times

Comment: @amy1122 Maybe  because the `isAfter` doesn't make sense in the comparisons done?   You have this: `if (first.getDay() > second.getDay()) return true; else if (first.getDay() < second.getDay())  return true;`.  You are returning `true` regardless of whether the first day is less than the second day.  You can't have `a < b` and at the same time `b < a`.  No wonder the sort goes haywire.